# Show all data for month to date

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

In Power BI, I am creating a grid to show specific data in a time period.  I want the grid to update everyday to show the data corresponding month to date.  I want my data to represent 9/7 - 10/7 and tomorrow I want it to update to show 9/8-10/8.  Essentially I want a measure in DAX to display all data from month to date.

Comment: Please provide more details and ask a question

Comment: @ELAi I updated the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from relative date filter in the right side tabs,

Select visualization and their is filter for date,

[image]

try with above method.